# Retrieve Blood Glucose Data using Google Fit HistoryAPI

Tags: android, google-fit

I'm trying to retrieve Blood Glucose Data using the Google Fit HistoryAPI. I used the HistoryAPI example for getting the step count (https://github.com/googlearchive/android-fit/tree/master/BasicHistoryApi) and tried to modify it so that I get blood glucose data instead of the step count.

I changed the fitnessOptions to:

```
 FitnessOptions fitnessOptions =
                FitnessOptions.builder()
                    .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_WRITE)
                    .addDataType(DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_WRITE)
                    .addDataType(TYPE_BLOOD_GLUCOSE, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
                    .addDataType(AGGREGATE_BLOOD_GLUCOSE_SUMMARY, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
                    .build();
```

and the readRequest looks like this:

```
DataReadRequest readRequest =
                new DataReadRequest.Builder()
                .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .aggregate(TYPE_BLOOD_GLUCOSE, AGGREGATE_BLOOD_GLUCOSE_SUMMARY)
                .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
                .build();
```

The step counter example works fine but I always get an empty dataset without any data points when I try to retrieve blood glucose data. What could be the problem here?

Comment: Any solutions to this? I'm running into the same issue. I can use the OAuth 2.0 playground to see 4 blood glucose data points, but when requesting from Android, no data points are returned.

Comment: @setlx do we have to get the app verified by google for HealthDataTypes like blood glucose, blood pressure?? What android permission are you using in the manifest for blood glucose?

Comment: How are you adding the glucose data points to Google Fit?

Comment: I have the same problem - anyone managed to figure this out?
I've added glucose data manually, directly through the Google Fit app.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify both the data type name and data source ID. In fact, if you specify both, the data type name is (currently) ignored.

If you specify the data source ID, that data source has to exist; if you specify the data type name, the "default" data source for that type is used; but it is allowed not to exist (for example, if the user has never actually written blood glucose data).

So, change your request to:

```
{
  "aggregateBy": [{
       "dataTypeName": "com.google.blood_glucose",
                  }],
  "bucketByTime": { "durationMillis": 86400000 },
  "startTimeMillis": 1578718800000,
  "endTimeMillis": 1580360400000
}
```